# How do I indentify this (Rach)? score

Tags: transcription

I have a small musical excerpt of which I am looking for the audio. I thought it was Rach, but I can't seem to find the score for it.

I had first thought it to be from Rach 3: 
https://musescore.com/classicman/scores/112955

But doesn't seem to be it. Can anybody give me pointers on how to find it? I've already tried google img. search. Something in Gmaj I would suspect...

[image]

Comment: Dare to complete the composers name? Even if I assume, that I'm guessing right, your (btw. off-topic) question should at least support  searching.

Answer (score 2):

Found it by searching on youtube for Rachmaninoff with the name of the mode/key.

Moment Musicaux Op. 16 No. 4